# Consumer-producer model with OpenMP

Tags: model, openmp, consumer, producer

I am trying to implement a single-producer-multiple-consumer model using OpenMP (I know that I could as well go for boost threads which might be better suited).

Here is my code, which is fairly simple and uses a thread-aware queue type:

```
bool producer_finished = false;

#pragma omp parallel default( none ) shared( producer_finished, buffer, datagen )
{
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        { // single producer

            while( datagen ) {
                DType data = datagen.next()
                buffer.push( data );
            }

            producer_finished = true;
            #pragma omp flush( producer_finished )

        } // end omp section

        #pragma omp section
        {
            #pragma omp for schedule( static, 1 )
            for ( int i = 0; i < omp_get_max_threads() - 1; ++i ) {

                while ( ! producer_finished ) {

                    #pragma omp critical( buffer )
                    {
                        DType = buffer.pop();
                    }

                    processData( data );
                    outputData( data );

                    #pragma omp flush( producer_finished )
                }
            } // end omp for
        } // end omp section

    } //end omp sections
} // end omp parallel
```

The problem here is that the producer starts and pushes data until the buffer is full but the consumers never start. If I remove the section around the "for pragma" the same happens. Can you see whats wrong with my approach?

I also get this warning during compilation:

```
warning: work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing, critical, ordered or master region
```

It refers to the nesting of the for loop in the section. What would be the correct way to do it in this case?

Thanks for your feedback.

Edit: Just found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916411/openmp-for-loop-inside-section), set_omp_nested(1) does not help me. I will try putting it in separate functions...

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP is designed for parallel computation, it's not a general purpose threading library. So trying to do a producer/consumer loop with OpenMP is just using the wrong tool, IMHO.

Comment: Ok, this is also my impression and I think I will implement it using boost threads. I just wanted to have a fast implementation using existing code and since I knew some OpenMP already... (though it should be possible using boost sections/tasks)

Answer (score 0):

your OpenMP code is syntactically wrong.
This is what the compiler is telling you.
A parallel section and a paralle loop are both worksharing constructs and they may not be nested inside immedeately each other.
You could add an inner parallel loop around the for construct and thus use nested parallelism, which you may need to explicitely enable.

Furthermore the use of the flush directive is not sufficient. 
You also need to synchronize the data you are working on.
It is highely recommended to use flush without a list - if at all.

You may want to pose OpenMp related questions to the forum on www.openmp.org to talk to the OpenMP expers.

best regards,
Dieter

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the producer-consumer pattern using boost threads and it works like a charm. For me, OpenMP is out of business unless I have to parallelize basic serial code with many for loops.

Answer (score 0):

See an example of the correct use of `flush` in the [OpenMP V3.0 specification](http://www.compunity.org/speci/spec30.pdf), appendix A.21.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the whole #pragma omp for into a function and change it into #pragma omg parallel for.

before executing the current #pragma omp parallel activate nested parallelism with omp_set_nested(1).