# OpenMP - Assign different threads to two for loops in the same parallel region

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have two for loops that I want to parallelize, and I want half the threads to work on the first loop, and the other half to work on the second. But it seems OpenMP doesn't allow `for` directives inside a `section`. Is there another way to do this?

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    int i,j;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            printf("Thread %d, i %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);

        #pragma omp for
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
            printf("Thread %d, j %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Thread 0, i 0
Thread 1, i 1
Thread 0, j 0
Thread 1, j 1
```

But I'm trying to get

```
Thread 0, i 0
Thread 1, i 1
Thread 2, j 0
Thread 3, j 1
```

Comment: I believe `#pragma omp for` only applies to a single `for` statement that follows.

Comment: @Groo Yes, I'm not trying to use one `for` directive for both loops. I'm trying to find a way to spread the threads between two different `#pragma omp for` directives.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916905/69809) what you're looking for? I.e. enabling [nested parallelism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html)?

Comment: @Groo Yes, that works. Can you write it as an answer?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to that other question, though technically not wrong, is not what you are looking for. Jonathan Dursi's answer is.